# iterating different length arrays and replace values

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, for-loop

I have a dataframe that looks like this:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'col1': [[[1,5,3],[0,0,0]], [[1,2,3],[0,0,0], [1,2,3]]]})

# which looks like this:
    col1
0   [[1, 5, 3], [0, 0, 0]]
1   [[1, 2, 3], [0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 3]]
```

I also have another array (a):

```
a = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4], [5]])
```

I want to replace the value in every second position from df with values from a.
So for example, I want to make dataframe that looks like this (every second value is changed from each array):

```
    col1
0   [[1, 1, 3], [0, 2, 0]]
1   [[1, 3, 3], [0, 4, 0], [1, 5, 3]]
```

This is how I approached it:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp = df.loc[i, "col1"]
    for k in range(len(a)):
        for j in range(len(temp)):
            temp[j][1] = a[k][0]
    print(temp)
```

which result in :

```
[[1, 5, 3], [0, 5, 0]]
[[1, 5, 3], [0, 5, 0], [1, 5, 3]]
```

Can anyone please help me how to figure this problem out??
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be looping over `a` with a nested loop, as that will create a cross product. Just increment an index variable and use that to get the next element of the array.

```
k = 0
for i in range(len(df)):
    temp = df.loc[i, "col1"]
    for j in range(len(temp)):
        temp[j][1] = a[k][0]
        k += 1
    print(temp)
```

Comment: how can I output temp result from k=0 because doing this will only output the last number for k and result in [[1, 3, 3], [0, 4, 0], [1, 5, 3]]. I want temp to contain all the result at the end.

Comment: `temp` is a reference into `df`.

Answer (score 1):

A simple way could be to transform the array into an iterator:

```
i = iter(a.ravel())
for L in df['col1']:
    for l in L:
        l[1] = next(i, l[1])
```

*NB. using here the original value as default in case the array is shorter than the number of sublists*

output:

```
                                col1
0             [[1, 1, 3], [0, 2, 0]]
1  [[1, 3, 3], [0, 4, 0], [1, 5, 3]]
```

Comment: It looks like you are trying to accept both answers, you can only choose one ;)

Comment: ah I see haha thanks!  I am still curious what you meant by things you wrote on NB. What do you mean by using the original value as a default? Where in the code can I specify that?

Comment: Try with `a = np.array([[1], [2], [3], [4]])` ;)